# Load wordpress page after an ajax call finish

Tags: javascript, ajax, wordpress

I have an ajax call to an API and based on the response I want to redirect my users, the API call is pretty basic and works fine:

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
      $.ajax({
        url: '//apicall-url',
        dataType: 'json',
        async: false,
        success: function(obj) {
           //redirect goes here
        }
      });
    });
```

My problem is that the current wordpress page is loading and then doing the redirect once the ajax call is "success" any suggestion on how to to this correctly (I'm a WP newbie)?

I also tried using the wp_enqueue_script function but got the same result.

I tried to do this in the header and body with no luck.

Comment: why made redirect on ajax finish? get your data on request and redirect where you need it

Comment: My ajax call have the page name I need to redirect the user, I need to wait for the call to get the page URL

Answer (score 0):

You need do your api call before page and scripts will be loaded. Try call your API from PHP side. Look `template_redirect` hook. This is the best hook to create redirects.

Comment: How can I do my API call before page and scripts load? That's my main issue. I need to wait for the API to finish.

Comment: Your ajax use ajax? What about cUrl on php? You can do api calls from back-end side. Or wp_remote_get function. But this is back function. Why you need ajax? Can you do same functionality via php?

Comment: I can do the same functionality but I don't have access to the php files, I'm trying to build this so the customer can "copy-paste" the code in the header

Comment: Ok. But (document).ready event is coming when page full load. Try another event. And include in head. But this bad practice, because page can be loaded if your ajax call will be long time.

Answer (score 0):

My issue here was the "document ready" waiting for the ajax call changing this worked fine, here is my code:

```
    (function($) { //<-This is an anonymous function that instantaneously runs.
      $.ajax({
        url: '//apicall-url',
        dataType: 'json',
        async: false,
        success: function(obj) {
          //redirect goes here
       }
      });
    })( jQuery );  //<----passing jquery to avoid any conflict with other libraries.
```